Passing a socket to a function and modifying it, or creating a socket inside the function and returning it
I am creating a simple python ASGI server and I have doubts about my implementation of the function that creates the server's socket.
Should I create the server's socket inside the function and return it like this:
class Server:
    def __init__(self, host: Optional[str] = None,
                 port: Optional[int] = None,
                 debug_mode: bool = False) -> None:
        self.host = host if host is not None else socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
        self.port = port if port is not None else 8000
        self.server_sock = self.initialize_server()
        self.debug_mode = debug_mode

    def initialize_server(self) -> Optional[socket.socket]:
        try:
            server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            server_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            server_sock.setblocking(False)
            server_sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
            return server_sock
        except socket.error as e:
            return None

Or should I pass an empty socket object to the function, modify it, like so:
class Server:
    def __init__(self, host: Optional[str] = None,
                 port: Optional[int] = None,
                 debug_mode: bool = False) -> None:
        self.host = host if host is not None else socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
        self.port = port if port is not None else 8000
        self.server_sock = None
        self.initialize_server()
        self.debug_mode = debug_mode

    def initialize_server(self) -> Optional[socket.socket]:
        try:
            self.server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.server_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            self.server_sock.setblocking(False)
            self.server_sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        except socket.error as e:
            self.server_sock = None

I would like to know if one implementation is preferable over the other, why, and if it can be implemented even better somehow.

IMO you will probably use the socket later after using your initialize_server method. So you should keep your second snippet to avoid constantly passing the server AND the socket to each function targetting this connection.
After typing correction, my favorite option is:
class Server:
    def __init__(self, host: Optional[str] = None,
                 port: int = 8000,
                 debug_mode: bool = False) -> None:
        self.host = host if host is not None else socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
        self.port: int = port
        self.server_sock: Optional[socket.socket] = None
        self.initialize_server()
        self.debug_mode = debug_mode

    def initialize_server(self) -> None:
        try:
            self.server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.server_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            self.server_sock.setblocking(False)
            self.server_sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        except socket.error as e:
            self.server_sock = None

One more advice, start to log everything when you handle your socket (example: at the exception you should log the error with logging module)

First, thanks for the advice and the quick answer. I do in fact use logging here i just removed it to simplify the problem. Though I'm not sure I understand what you meant. What am i precisely avoiding if I'm using the second code snippet? And also what did you mean by passing the server and the socket to each function targeting this connection? couldn't i just pass the server object itself alone? Thanks

Yep, if you need to use something into your server instance and your socker you will have to integrate these objects into each signature of your functions. It's more readable to limit number of arguments into the signatures IMO. The second snippet avoid this. Example:
  if server.debug:
    server.socket.send(b'Debug  mode ON')

Moreover, you can add method handling socket directly into your Server object.
     if self.debug_mode:
       self.socket.send(b'Debug mode ON')

@Eyal_Raveh

Forgive me, I still don’t understand why is this related to which method implementation I use. The server’s attributes will be set exactly the same either way.

Your question isn't really about code optimization, your two snippets will do the same as you said. So even with a same efficiency, your second snippet is more readable and maintainable.
